# What does MyClass.class in Java represent?

Tags: java

I have come across code in the form:

```
MyClass.class.getName();
```

Is .class a property?

Is it applicable to ALL classes? (is it inherited from Object class?)

What type of object is returned by .class ?

What other functions like getName() does the .class have?

I realize that this is a very basic question, but I wasn't able to locate comprehensive information in the Javadocs, and it would be really helpful if some practical application of .class could be given.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MyClass.class` is a literal value of type [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) (the same way as `"..."` is a literal value of type `String`).

It's available for all classes and interfaces, and also for primitive types (`int.class`).

Since `Class` is generic, type of `MyClass.class` is `Class<MyClass>`, so that you can do this:

```
Class<MyClass> c = MyClass.class;
MyClass o = c.newInstance(); // No cast needed, since newInstance() on Class<T> returns T
```

Methods of `Class` can be found in [its javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: I have heard this term 'literal value' earlier also. Still having some problem understanding it. Could you please explain further, or point me to relevant information?

Comment: @Shailesh: Literal value is a textual representation of value of some type in the source code. So, `"Hello, world"` is a literal value of type `String`, `42` is a literal value of type `int`, `true` is a literal value of type `boolean`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`.class` returns object of class [Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and yes it applicable to all classes. Is Java core class.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a property. "class" is a special keyword that you can use to get Class object of the class by its name. You can call `java.lang.Object.class`, but not `obj.class`. Instead you should use `obj.getClass()`.